# How to handle errors inside Catch block

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

In my application I am getting System.NullReferenceException for my REST call.
This Error is caused by code inside Catch block.
Is it a good idea to put another try catch block inside Catch block?
In the below code following line of code in Catch block is throwing error.

```
resultObject.ErrorResponse = _client.GetErrorResponse(Of List(Of ErrorResponseObject))(ex, "{""errors"":")
```

How do I fix this issue, so that user doesn't see any error.
Here is my code.

```
    Public Shared Function POSTCall()
_client = New BaseClient()
    Try

        strJsonResponse = _client.ExecuteURI(serviceUrl, requestHeader, "POST", resultObject, False, False)

    Catch ex As WebException            
        resultObject.ErrorResponse = _client.GetErrorResponse(Of List(Of ErrorResponseObject))(ex, "{""errors"":")      'This line causing error

        If Not IsNothing(resultObject.ErrorResponse) Then
            ' do some work
        End If

    Catch Exp As Exception
        'Supress the error. Let user goto next step.
    Finally
        _client = Nothing
    End Try

    Return resultObject
End Function
```

Comment: It's rare that a `NullReferenceException` should be thrown at all because you should generally be checking whether a reference is null first, either explicitly, by null propagation or the `If` operator.  You obviously already know how to do that because you're doing it on the very next line, even if that's not the best way.  There may be cases where it makes sense though and, if this is one of them, an exception handler inside a `Catch` block is OK.

Comment: Is the issue that `_client` is null, or is the issue that a NullRefException is thrown by `GetErrorResponse`?  If the latter, given the usage here and assuming you control that function, it seems like a bug in that function that it might throw.  If the former, test for it instead of having it trip when you try to use the object.

Comment: As an aside, there's no good reason to use the `IsNothing` function, when you can just use the operator form `Is Nothing`.  Also, there is an `IsNot` operator now so you can just say `If resultObject.ErrorResponse IsNot Nothing` which is much easier to read.

Comment: _client is not null. This issue happens when there is a time out. Do you think Adding third Catch block like  "Catch nullRefEx As NullReferenceException"  will fix the issue?

Comment: I'd imagine it would fix the issue, but it would be better if you can make it so that there is no NullRefException at all.  The issue would have to be either within `GetErrorResponse`---in which case I would recommend to fix `GetErrorResponse` so that it returns something useful instead of throwing---or it would be that `resultObject` is null---in which case you have what Eric Lippert would call a boneheaded exception that is easy to resolve without an expensive try-catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to catch the error Inside the catch block. This is especially appropriate since what the code is trying to do is to get more info about an error that has already occurrred. Of course, it might be a good idea to log any error occurring, even if the application can continue.

Comment: Are you suggesting that add another try catch block inside the Catch block? Please advise

Comment: Yes, because you are trying to retrieve additional info about the error. If that fails, you want to ignore it.

Comment: As above, the first thing you should try to do is eliminate the exception.  Only if that's not possible should you resort to adding an extra try-catch within the catch.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer doing things that are not asynchronous inside the catch. In a case where I need to perform an asynchronous function say rolling back a database transaction, I'll just throw the error and have another asynchronous function handle it in it's catch block in a synchronous way